# Data Encryption in Data Layer with ASP.NET Core Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am currently designing a web application where the data needs to be stored **encrypted**.

Planned technologies used:

- ASP.NET Core API
- ASP.NET Core Entity Framework
- MS SQL Server 2016
- any Web Frontend

Because of the specification we need to store all data encrypted in the database.

Which would be a good approach to achieve this while still be able to use the **Entity Framework** & **LINQ**, so the developer does not have to take care about the encryption.

Is it possible to encrypt the whole database?

To clarify, the encryption between the web frontend & the API isn't something that's related to this question.

Answer (score 2):

SQL 2016 came up with the new encryption feature. Please take a look.

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/exploration-of-sql-server-2016-always-encrypted-part-1.html

It is not a good idea to encrypt a whole database for the performance reasons. Go through the article. The encryption & decryption happens with the help of ADO.NET layer.

Comment: ASP.Net Core currently does not support Always Encrypted (yet) -
 http://stackoverflow.com/a/41175581/5235385

Comment: Yeh, you may be right.. Did you check it yourself. MS couldn't have missed this important feature.

Answer (score 2):

Encryption algorithm are slow so, Encrypting whole database is going to affect performance. Encrypting whole database require more space. Good Approach is that encrypt crucial data like Username ,Password ,Contact-number, Email etc. Good approach is that encrypt data while inserting into database and decrypt it while reading. you can create  library for encryption operation. you can use `Aes provider`
You can add `[Encrypted]` attribute to you property.

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Encrypted]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Encrypted]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Encrypted]
    public int Email{ get; set; }
}

public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    // Get key and IV from a Base64String or any other ways.
    // You can generate a key and IV using "AesProvider.GenerateKey()"
    private readonly byte[] _encryptionKey = ...; 
    private readonly byte[] _encryptionIV = ...;
    private readonly IEncryptionProvider _provider;

    public DbSet<UserEntity> Users { get; set; }

    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
        this._provider = new AesProvider(this._encryptionKey, this._encryptionIV);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.UseEncryption(this._provider);
    }
}
```

refer this site:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/develop-using-always-encrypted-with-net-framework-data-provider?view=sql-server-ver15